# Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6 - label checkbox radio buttons break entire toolbar styling

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

Using the `<label class="btn btn-secondary"><input type="radio" value="active"> Active</label>` breaks the entire tool bar in Bootstrap 4 - Alpha 6

[See Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/YEnHMD7XIw)

**This is the visual of good and bad code**

[image: This is the visual of good and bad code]

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" >

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Select All</button>
    </div>
    <div [(ngModel)]="toolbar.active" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic" class="btn-group btn-group-sm" (ngModelChange)="onChanges('activeChanged')">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" value="active"> Active
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" value="inactive"> Inactive
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" value="all"> All
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 250px;">
        <input id="search" [(ngModel)]="toolbar.search" (ngModelChange)="onChanges($event)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    </div>

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm float-xs-right" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="onChanges('refresh')">Refresh</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="['new']">New</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Debug</button>
    </div>

</div>

<br/>
```

**This altered code breaks entire formatting**

[image: This altered code breaks entire formatting]

Comment: Did you find a solution? Please accept an answer, or update the question so it can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work pretty well..

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Select All</button>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm" (ngmodelchange)="onChanges('activeChanged')">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" value="active"> Active
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" value="inactive"> Inactive
        </button >
        <button  class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" value="all"> All
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-sm" style="width: 250px;">
        <input id="search" [(ngmodel)]="toolbar.search" (ngmodelchange)="onChanges($event)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm ml-auto" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" (click)="onRefresh()">Refresh</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [routerlink]="['new']">New</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Debug</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/SkZIflTsOZ

Note: I'm **not sure that the inputs inside buttons are suppored** in the `btn-group`. Also note the docs say..

> "Feel free to mix input groups with button groups in your toolbars. Similar to the example above, you’ll likely need some utilities though to space things properly."

Comment: Whilst this seems to work visually, it is not the way the bootstrap ng controls work and they seem to need to work with <label><input type='checkbox'></label>

Comment: Yeah, inputs require labels so perhaps the toolbar is not the best place for them. As mentioned in the docs you'll need to space things properlely.

Comment: That's unfortunate because this all works fine in Bootstrap 4 - Alpha 4 and of course bootstrap 3